# Populating Twitter's data-text attribute with angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

I have this HTML code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="{{ controller.inviteToCommentString(controller.username) }}">Ask {{ controller.username }} to comment!</a>
```

But when rendered to a "share" button using twitter's code, the text is not rendered correctly. When the button is clicked, it opens a "tweet" window and prepopulates this text: `{{ controller.inviteToCommentString(controller.username) }}`

How do I make the Tweet button populate my personal message using Angular?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for but if it helps you can share some text in twitter using the following api

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?
```

for your case it may look like the following

```
<a href="{{'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?'+controller.inviteToCommentString(controller.username)}}" class="twitter-share-button">Ask {{ controller.username }} to comment!</a>
```

hope that helped.